# print("\r"), not working as intended when running from task scheduler

Tags: python, windows

If I start cmd.exe, enter the python console and test out the following code, the console prints to only one line as is intended.

If I run the same code by starting the python file from the task scheduler, it prints out the same sentence on a new line every second.

I want it to behave the same as if I was running it through cmd.exe.(ie: to print to one line only and overwrite current line each time)

I tried making the task scheduler run the python script in cmd.exe but all it appears to do is run the taskeng.exe as the outer shell.

### code

```
import time
reportToCheck = 'Application and Acquisition Loader2'
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(60):
        print("\rscript - %s - not yet complete, checking again in: %02d:%02d" %(reportToCheck, 4-x, 59-y)),
        time.sleep(1)
```

expected: print to one line only

actual (when running in task scheduler): prints to a new line each time

Comment: What are the executable and command line arguments for the task? It seems you're running the task via Python 3.

Comment: Running python.exe *from* cmd.exe (not *in* cmd.exe) makes no difference. The CMD shell simple spawns the process via `CreateProcessW` and waits for it to exit. The only interaction, and it's a stretch to call it that, is the fact that Python inherits CMD's console instead of allocating its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default python `print` behavior:

```
print(*objs, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

As you can see, all print calls are making a new line by default. To omit such behavior you can specify end symbol yourself:

```
print("\rscript - %s - not yet complete ...", end="")
```

Comment: thank you (i forgot to mention i did try that). my python version is 2.7.10 and for some reason it doesnt allow the 'end' argument. the error is 'invalid syntax'. your suggestion does work on my home installation of python (3.6). I tried calling print without the brackets but still no luck.

Comment: Did you try ```from __future__ import print_function```?